# Ontario open work permit: What next? Can I travel?

Tags: paperwork

I live in Scarborough - Ontario, granted me an open work permit until 2016. I know I need to remove the SIN card, and health card. What are yet my responsibilities? During the duration of a work permit can I travel to Europe and back in Canada?

Comment: You need to remove a SIN card? What? Do you mean obtain? What 'range' are you considering 'responsibilities'? Health? Tax? It's a bit too broad at the moment, please edit and make it a bit more specific to your problem at hand.